# How to batch print word files with titles?

Tags: microsoft-word

I have a folder of Word files that I need to print. I'm looking for a way to embed the file names as header/footer on these pages, if possible even number the pages to keep them organized.

Is there a way to do this?

I'm using Office 2007 on Windows 7.

Answer (score 1):

From [this site](http://www.wordbanter.com/showthread.php?t=74001), here is a macro that prints all documents in a given folder with the full file path added into the header, right aligned, 8pt Arial:

```
Sub PrintWithFileNames()
    On Error GoTo err_FolderContents
    Dim FirstLoop As Boolean
    Dim DocList As String
    Dim DocDir As String

    With Dialogs(wdDialogCopyFile)
        If .Display 0 Then
            DocDir = .Directory
        Else
            MsgBox "Cancelled by User"
            Exit Sub
        End If
    End With

    If Documents.Count 0 Then
        Documents.Close SaveChanges:=wdPromptToSaveChanges
    End If

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    FirstLoop = True

    If Left(DocDir, 1) = Chr(34) Then
        DocDir = Mid(DocDir, 2, Len(DocDir) - 2)
    End If

    DocList = Dir$(DocDir & "*.doc")

    Do While DocList ""
        Documents.Open DocList
        Selection.EndKey Unit:=wdStory
        ActiveWindow.ActivePane.View.SeekView = wdSeekCurrentPageHeader

        With Selection
            .EndKey Unit:=wdStory
            .Font.Name = "Arial"
            .Font.Size = "8"
            .ParagraphFormat.Alignment = wdAlignParagraphRight
            .TypeText vbCr & ActiveDocument.FullName
        End With

        ActiveWindow.ActivePane.View.SeekView = wdSeekMainDocument
        ActiveDocument.PrintOut
        ActiveDocument.Close SaveChanges:=wdDoNotSaveChanges
        DocList = Dir$()
        FirstLoop = False
    Loop

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Exit Sub

    err_FolderContents:
    MsgBox Err.Description
    Exit Sub
End Sub
```

Comment: please expand on your answer, @justme.

Answer (score 0):

In the header or footer, you can add a "field" that is the file-name.  How you insert fields, is dependent on the version of Word you're using.   After adding the filename-field to your header/footer... and saving your documents in a folder, you can simply right-click & click print.

Comment: I need to do this for 19 files, which makes this less feasible.

Comment: Less feasible how?  If the files are created properly, printing them is quick & simple.   Modifying 19-files is another subject.  It's simply a matter of ... you should-have done it correctly to start with.  Word is designed to create printed-documents... not documents that can be sent to a parser to modify the output before printing.

Comment: These are summaries sent from my teacher over a period of time in several emails, I did not create them.
And of course I meant that editing them would be hard, I know how to right click>print.

Answer (score 0):

One idea is to print a header page before each document.  Your printer settings may allow for this and may even include the file name from word automatically.  If not, you could write a quick batch script that will print the file name page then print the document.